# What does the "Bird/Worm" slider do?

Tags: cultist-simulator

I've noticed this slider in the settings menu:

[image: Bird/Worm Slider]

There seem to only be two options: Bird and Worm.

Is this some kind of difficulty menu? What exactly does it do, if anything?

Comment: There's no manual, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Enigmatics](http://weatherfactory.biz/enigma-what-it-is-what-it-isnt/) say this is part of an [alternate reality game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_reality_game).

The slider is used to decipher enigmas in real life, and does nothing really useful in the game.